# Alfresco Error alfresco.fileupload is not a constructor

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am a beginner Alfresco programmer. I have a problem with Alfresco.FileUpload (). On one page this method works, but on the other it gives the error alfresco.fileupload is not a constructor. Tried connecting to components / upload / file-upload.js page but it was unsuccessful.

Comment: Can you please explain where its working and where its not, also please post the error logs.

Comment: To fix the error, I initialized the javascript directly on the pagen the page ->
 <alfresco-config>
   <config>
        <forms>
            <dependencies>
                <js src="/components/upload/file-upload.js"/>
            </dependencies>
        </forms>
    </config>
</alfresco-config>   
This helped fix the error, but another appeared -> "No instance of uploader type 'Alfresco.DNDUpload' exists."

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use "Alfresco.getFileUploadInstance()" instead.

From file-upload.js:

```
/**
* FileUpload constructor.
*
* FileUpload is considered a singleton so constructor should be treated as private,
* please use Alfresco.getFileUploadInstance() instead.
*
* @param {string} htmlId The HTML id of the parent element
* @return {Alfresco.FileUpload} The new FileUpload instance
* @constructor
* @private
*/
```

Comment: I changed to - "Alfresco.getFileUploadInstance()" . 
Another error appeared - No instance of uploader type 'Alfresco.DNDUpload' exists.

Comment: Are you doing dnd uploading? What version of Alfresco?   You may want to check out this project for inspiration: https://github.com/softwareloop/uploader-plus/blob/master/surf/src/main/amp/config/alfresco/site-webscripts/com/softwareloop/uploader-plus/uploader/dnd-upload.get.html.ftl